# Why is only the last added trace displayed when adding traces iteratively to a Plotly object using R?

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

```r
library(plotly)

V <- data.frame(t, A, B, C, D, E, F)

pic <- plot_ly(V, x = ~t) %>% 
         add_trace(y = ~40000*exp(-t/7), name = "P(t)",
                   type = "scatter", mode="lines",
                   line=list(color="gray",width=2)
                  ) %>%
        layout(yaxis=list(title="Amount / million euros",zeroline=TRUE),
               xaxis = list(title="t",zeroline = TRUE)
              )

CLR <- c("darkblue", "powderblue", "mediumaquamarine", "darkred", "wheat", "tan")
for (j in 1:6)
{
  pic <- pic %>%
    add_trace(y = ~V[,j+1], name = colnames(V)[j+1],
              type = "scatter", mode = 'lines+markers',
              marker=list(size=8,color=CLR[j]),
              line=list(color=CLR[j],width=1.5)
             )
  print(pic)
}
```

I have a dataframe of 7 columns, `V`, and I want to plot the last 6 columns against the first one by adding one trace each time to the plotly object `pic`. Yet when I print out `pic` at the end of each iteration, only the last added trace is displayed and all the previous traces are gone. Legends are all there, though. Why does this happen? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible solutions.

```
set.seed(123)
t <- 1:20
A <- 4*exp(-t/7)+rnorm(20)*0.1
B <- 4*exp(-t/7)+rnorm(20)*0.2
C <- 4*exp(-t/7)+rnorm(20)*0.3
D <- 4*exp(-t/7)+rnorm(20)*0.4
E <- 4*exp(-t/7)+rnorm(20)*0.5
F <- 4*exp(-t/7)+rnorm(20)*0.6
V <- data.frame(t, A, B, C, D, E, F)

pic <- plot_ly(data=V, x = ~t) %>% 
         add_trace(y = ~4*exp(-t/7), name = "P(t)",
                   type = "scatter", mode="lines",
                   line=list(color="gray",width=2)
                  ) %>%
        layout(yaxis=list(title="Amount / million euros",zeroline=TRUE),
               xaxis = list(title="t",zeroline = TRUE)
              )

CLR <- c("darkblue", "powderblue", "mediumaquamarine", "darkred", "wheat", "tan")
for (j in 1:6) {
  pic <- pic %>%
    add_trace(x = V[,1], y = V[,j+1], name = colnames(V)[j+1],
              type = "scatter", mode = 'lines+markers',
              marker=list(size=8, color=CLR[j]),
              line=list(color=CLR[j], width=1.5, inherit.aes=F)
             )
}
print(pic)
```

Or

```
for (j in 1:6) {
  df <- data.frame(x=V[,1], y=V[,j+1])
  pic <- pic %>%
    add_trace(data=df, x = ~x, y = ~y, name = colnames(V)[j+1],
              type = "scatter", mode = 'lines+markers',
              marker=list(size=8, color=CLR[j]),
              line=list(color=CLR[j], width=1.5)
             )
}
```

[image]